# nginx setup for angularjs and php5 rest

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I'm trying to run an angularjs application along with an php application.
I made 2 folders ( client & api ) and I uploaded all my angular app files in client and all my php rest api into "api" directory.

I added into nginx:

```
location / {
      try_files $uri /client/index.html;
}
location /api/ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$args;
}
location /static {
      alias /var/www/www.sitename.com/htdocs/client/static/;
}
```

I'm wondering if is there a more elegant way to make this work, because right now if i want to add an exception to "location /" i need to go and modify nginx again.

Please advise.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?  I have the same problem within my app as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579481/angularjs-nginx-configuration-for-php-api

Comment: Is working like it is, but I haven't tried to make it better